# Self in protocol always need to be optional?

Tags: swift, properties, swift-protocols

Example:

```
internal protocol PropertyProtocol {
    var property: Self {
        get
    }
}
```

The only option I see to implement it, let us say in a class is

```
internal final class PropertyClass: PropertyProtocol {
    let property: PropertyClass

    internal init(otherOne pOtherOne: PropertyClass) {
        self.property = pOtherOne
    }
}
```

But then I do not see a possibility to use it.

```
let test: PropertyProtocol = PropertyProtocol(...) // hmm, how?
```

Does Self in a protocol property type declaration always have to be optional?

Comment: Yes, because that first instance doesn't have a `property` to which to refer.

Comment: As a stored property, yes it would have to be optional for you to create an instance. Although `Self` is more designed to be used with methods and calculated properties.

Comment: @originaluser2 Calculated properties! That's its use case. Please answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a stored property, indeed it would have to be optional for you to create an instance, as each instance would require the stored property to be assigned during initialisation – leading to recursive behaviour. Therefore `Self` doesn't make too much sense as a stored property; it's really more designed to be used with methods or *calculated* properties.

Depending on what you're using this for (seems like a fairly hypothetical example), you could implement a calculated property like so:

```
protocol PropertyProtocol {
    var property : Self { get }
}

final class PropertyClass : PropertyProtocol {
    var property : PropertyClass {
        get {
            return // ...
        }
        set {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

That way the class itself can manage the creation of the property when it's accessed, preventing the recursive behaviour of requiring it to be assigned during initialisation.